# When to use casting in C

Tags: c, casting

I have a statement in C code which I suspect may be giving me periodic errors, so want to make sure I am doing the right thing as it mixes types.
Objective is to change timebase from 1/32768 seconds to 1/1024, with all times 32 bit integers.

What I have is this:

```
ts_sys = latest_timestamp * VELO_TICKS_FROM_RTC;
```

Where ts_sys and latest_timestamp are both unsigned 32 bit integers.
VELO_TICKS_FROM_RTC is a define as follows:

```
#define VELO_TICKS_PER_SECOND         1024   
#define VELO_TICKS_FROM_RTC        (VELO_TICKS_PER_SECOND / 32768.0f)
```

Should I be using a cast here to make sure the division doesn't return an integer (which would be zero) and therefore return the wrong thing?  For example would this be better:

```
ts_sys = (uint32_t) ((float)latest_timestamp * VELO_TICKS_FROM_RTC);
```

but that seems like overkill..

Answer (score 3):

> Should I be using a cast here to make sure the division doesn't return an integer (which would be zero) and therefore return the wrong thing?

no, you are doing A/B, and B is a float, so the compiler promotes A to float and the result is a float!

Answer (score 0):

> "Should I be using a cast here to make sure the division doesn't return an integer?"

No, `1024` is of type `int` and `latest_timestamp` is of type `uint32_t`. Both get converted to `float` in the arithmetic expressions before the respective calculation is done:

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is float.
>
> C18, §6.3.1.8/1; "Usual arithmetic conversions"

---

> "but that seems like an overkill..."

It is.